# Ampersand conversion with Haml with Angular.js application

Tags: angularjs, haml, html-encode, html-escape-characters

I have an Angular.js application that I want to start using Haml with. My problem is some of my code doesn't convert properly.

I need to output the following:

```
<form name='userForm' class='admin-form form-horizontal' ng-submit='userForm.$valid && saveUser()' novalidate></form>
```

So in Haml, I write:

```
%form{:class => 'admin-form form-horizontal', :name => 'userForm', :'ng-submit'=>'userForm.$valid && saveUser()'}
```

The problem though is that the `&&` gets converted to `&amp;&amp;` so:

```
<form name='userForm' class='admin-form form-horizontal' ng-submit='userForm.$valid &amp;&amp; saveUser()' novalidate></form>
```

What can I do to prevent this? Also, is it possible to put each attribute of a tag in Haml on a separate line? I get errors when I try to do that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I got it to work by setting `no-escape-attrs` to `true` in the Gruntfile haml options:

```
haml:
      options:
        'no-escape-attrs': true
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [`escape_attrs` option](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Options.html#escape_attrs-instance_method) to false. How you do this will depend on how you are using Haml, [see the docs](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#options).

e.g. from the command line:

```
$haml --no-escape-attrs
%form{:class => 'admin-form form-horizontal', :name => 'userForm', :'ng-submit'=>'userForm.$valid && saveUser()'}
```

produces:

```html
<form class='admin-form form-horizontal' name='userForm' ng-submit='userForm.$valid && saveUser()'></form>
```

Comment: I am using Haml as a Grunt task. I added the "$haml --no-escape-attrs" line to my .haml file and it still did not work.

Comment: No, that is an example of what to type from the command line, not what to add to your `.haml` file. You need to find out how to set Haml options with Grunt and then set `:escape_attrs` to false.